# How do I use Hamcrests contains method with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest, junit5

[Screenshot of Java code in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU5re.png)

JUnit 5 does not seem to contain the require JAR for the Hamcrest imports below:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;
```

When i added the hamcrest-all-1.3.jar(see screenshot) it worked but it caused an error when i ran my tests.

I think the compiler does not like that there are duplicates in both the core jar in Junit and my JAR.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: The third line is not syntactically correct. Remove the `static` and replace the `.` at the end with a `;`. Then the import statements should compile and the rest should work itself out. If it doesn't, please include the error message on the imports in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hamcrest 1.3 should work with JUnit 5.1, most likely you have mixed up dependencies. If you have classpath conflicts with other dependencies you might want to use `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```